# How can I install drivers for nvidia gtx 560?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 12.04.1 and nVidia gtx 560

The "Additional Drivers" in system setting is empty!

How can I install the driver...?

Should I download them from the GeForce.com ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling the [X Updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) (see *Adding this PPA to your system*). It contains the latest stable release of the nVidia graphics drivers (`304.43` at the time of writing).

In case 'Additional Drivers' (actually that's Jocky) stays empty, install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Comment: gertvdijk You rock !!!
I installed the drivers as you guided...
Now it works fine for me full screen without nomodeset :)

Thanks!!!

Comment: @SAM You're really hitting a bug here. X-Updates PPA contains packages that most probably will be included in the future 12.10 release.